# When can I change the order of nth derivative and integral?

Tags: integration

there is theorem, which states that we can change order of first derivative of an integral as integral of first derivative, but we have to check if integral of derivative of absolute value of a integrand is finite, if it holds, than we can change order. What i have to check if i want to change order of nth derivative of an intgral? Can I check for nth derivative or i have to do it for the first, than second and so on... But in example I have "n". If i can check finitiness of nth right away, it must mean that lower order derivative have also finite integral? Thank you

Comment: You may be thinking of "differentiating under the integral sign," or the Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: Integrand most be cont. and continiously differentiable in Leibniz? What about nth derivative? Will it stay cont. diff. after first derivative? Thank you. I am sorry if its not smart question )

Comment: It might help if you write out formally what equality you are trying to express. I am not sure if I am visualizing it correctly.

Comment: I dont really know how to write, so :  n-th order derivative, than integral of some function, I want to solve this problem (and i should) as integral of n-th derivative of this function. But i dont know what should hold.